# react-native-init config files - unsure which ones to edit for absolute import paths

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack

I want to start using absolute import paths in my app, by following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/how-to-change-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths-for-imports-32ba6cce18a5). I have all of the same files as the tutorial has, except for `webpack.config.js`. I created my app 2 years ago, I think with `react-native init Vepo`, and it set it all up for me. I never did many configurations as it was automatic. I don't see a `webpack.config.js` file in my app so I am wondering what is the equivalent file in my app, so that I can follow the tutorial and adjust it for my app? If my project doesn't use webpack then I should not even get `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` as it won't work.

I only have these config files:

[image]

And these folders:

[image]

What is my equivalent config file of `webpack.config.js` so that I can look at my options of adding absolute import paths to my project?

Comment: Have you checked the `babel.config.js` file?

Comment: @Deadmano That file has: `module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `package.json` file within the directory you wish to import from which contains:

```
{
   "name":"src"
}
```

`src` being the name of the specific folder. Then you can `import x from 'src/x.js'` as an example.

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099?source=post_page---------------------------#issuecomment-221815006).

Comment: Thank you that works! I'm just working on getting rid of the flow error `Cannot resolve module 'src/xxx'`

Comment: `[options]
module.name_mapper='^src\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/\1'
module.name_mapper='^src$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src'
module.system.node.resolve_dirname='<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/'
module.name_mapper='^src\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/\1'` in `.flowconfig` got rid of false positive flow errors. Perfect.

Comment: What a workaround, but I'm glad that worked for you! All of the best with your project!